# I there any way to validate a number had been entered into an input?

Tags: validation, python-3.x, input

```
print("Now please enter a number")
No1 = int(input(">> "))
```

Is there any way that I could validate that the user had entered a number using a while loop and variables for example:

```
NumberInput1 = False

print("Now please enter a number")
while NumberInput = False
    No1 = int(input(">> "))
    #if a number was entered
    NumberInput1 = True
    #if a number wasn't entered
    NumberInput1 = False
    print("That is not a number try again")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I type-check variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463604/how-can-i-type-check-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try/except` to distinguish whether your string is convertible to an integer.

```
gotNumber = False
while not gotNumber:
    try:
        num = int(input('>> '))
        gotNumber = True
    except ValueError:
        print("That is not a number.")
```

Comment: Cool. There should be a button somewhere around here for you to accept the answer.